# How to limit number of apps running?

Tags: vb.net

I want to open 3 calc.exe; if I close one calc.exe then open another calc.exe.

A total of only 3 calc processes.

```
    Dim i As Integer

    While i <= 3
        For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses()

            If p.ProcessName = "calc" Then
                MsgBox(p.ProcessName)
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next
        Process.Start("calc.exe")

    End While
```

Comment: Do you want exactly 3 copies of calc, no-more, no-less?
Also, do you want this running just once or constantly (without ending)?

Comment: `How to limit number of apps running?` you would need to constantly pull the processes...

Answer (score 2):

You could add a Timer with whatever interval you want, say 1000, to check every second, and then have it call this in it's Tick event:

```
Private Sub CountCalcs()

    ' Dim i As Integer = 0

    ' For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses()

    '   If p.ProcessName = "calc" Then i += 1

    ' Next

    ' Using Linq, as suggested by Codexer.
    Dim i As Integer = Process.GetProcesses().Where(Function(p) p.ProcessName = "calc").Count

    ' Open new or Kill Calcs until a total of 3 are running
    Do Until i = 3

      if i > 3 then

        p.kill() ' This is prob the wrong way to kill it when using Linq, but I don't have a debugger handy atm.
        i -= 1

      else if i < 3 then

        Process.Start("calc.exe")
        i += 1

      end if

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: `Process.GetProcesses().Where(proc => proc.ProcessName == "calc")` no need to get other processes you don't care about. Then clean up other code you don't need.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Yep. Good eye.

Comment: `Process.GetProcesses().Where(Function(proc) proc.ProcessName = "calc")`, sorry I forgot it was `vb` :)

Comment: Also, if there are 4 processes named calc, before your `Do` loop, it will cause an infinite condition.

Comment: @tgolisch Good eye as well. Ok, I THINK I got it all now, with the exception of the `p.kill`, but I can't test that at the moment, lol.